# Is it a bad idea to set a Context field variable (getActivity().getApplicationContext()) on every fragment?

Tags: android, android-context

I tend to call `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` a lot in my fragments, would it be a bad idea to just to set a Context field variable by default on my fragments?  We are starting android development at work and I don't want to create any bad habits for the group.

Comment: it does not make sense, since you can access getActivity anywhere in the Fragmnet

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to use `getApplicationContext()` , just use the Activity context , also in some conditions getActivity() might return null in Fragments, so i think getting Activity Context on `onAttach(Activity activity)` is a better way in Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use the Application Context while you could use directly the Activity instance.

Please notice that if the fragment is detached from the activity the getActivity() will return you Null as a result. So you have to see the application logic.

If the fragment needs to do something even after it is detached from the activity then keep the activity as a field, otherwise simply check if (getActivity() != null)

Answer (score 0):

One reason where I have seen it useful to store the application context as a field in a fragment is when the fragment is of the type that don't have any UI and it's purpose is to start a task that does something in the background, and the fragment also have the `setRetainInstance(true);` to be kept on rotation.

In that case the activity can be recreated on rotation but the task that do the background thing in the background can continue and is held by the fragment. Let's say the result of that task have fetched something from Internet and then want to store it in a database, then the callback for the task comes back to the fragment. A call to `getActivity()`could result in null due to a potential rotation, the application context is however kept so therefore a field with the application context is handy because it is not destroyed when the activity is. The `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` would need to be called in the onAttach() method and stored to a field.